# Oracle Spatial: how to query all polygons what are connected (recursivelly)?

Tags: sql, oracle, spatial

Let's say we have 6 polygons ( A,B,C,D,E, F)in Spatial database.
A touches B, 
B touches C and D, 
E and F are not connected to other polygons.

```
A - B
   / \
  C   D       E     F
```

Having Polygon A, I need to query all polygons connected to it , and do it "recursivelly" Cannot describe it better. So the query by A should return A, B, C, D.

Of course, it is possible to do programmatically, first using SDO_RELATE query B by A, and then query C and D by B. But is it possible to do the task with a single query?

Comment: It would be more understndable if you could provide your tables as examples.. If you want to have a drilldown functionality, depending on your table structure, I would recommend you check Oracle's START WITH  CONNECT BY PRIOR functionality

Comment: Calipso, my legacy tables design is quite complicated, so If I put them in original question, it would make the things overcomplicated. Thank You for "START WITH CONNECT BY PRIOR" suggestion, I should make some research on it.